# Drupal custom module, turn tinymce off programatically?

Tags: drupal, tinymce, textarea

In a Drupal, on a textarea in a custom module, how can I turn tinymce editor (tinytinymce) off programatically?

```
  $form['subject'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Please Enter Subject'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => 5, 
    '#description' => t('some description'), 
 '#suffix' => 'a suffix',  
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for comments.  You should be able to adapt for your form.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
        if ($form['#id'] == 'comment-form') {
                $form['comment_filter']['format'] = array(); // nuke wysiwyg from comments
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, editor_id); // the editor_id equals the id of your textarea
```

Comment: @Aalok Parish: this is not a comment, but the solution to the askers problem!